# (C++ Memory Editing) Converting "THREADSTACK0" to an address

Tags: c++, cheat-engine, memory-editing

I have gotten a pointer to an address in cheat engine, and when I was trying to port it into c++ to set up a hotkey for it I ran into a problem. Cheat engine tells me `"THREADSTACK0"-000009C0` (and some offsets) points to my address, but I have no clue how to get the value of `"THREADSTACK0"-000009C0`. Please keep in mind I am new to c++ so don't overload me with information. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i got you a link that might help you, the thing seems to be that that's not a valid memory adress but some adress handled by Cheat Engine. You can get a memory adress from that THREADSTACK0 thingy from inside CheatEngine, if I got it right.

Here's the link:
http://forum.cheatengine.org/viewtopic.php?p=5487976